# Oracle 10g Forms Connection error 500

Tags: oracle, forms, oracle10g, oracleforms, oracle-fusion-middleware

[image]

I have the following log in Java Console:

```
2017-Oct-28  17:45:31.733 WUT[setProperty()] Setting property WUC_GET_LOCAL_PROPERTY to syslib.JNIsharedstubs.dll
2017-Oct-28  17:45:31.733 WUT[getProperty()] Getting property WUC_GET_LOCAL_PROPERTY
Reconnecting (try 1 of 60)...
Reconnecting (try 2 of 60)...
Reconnecting (try 3 of 60)...
Reconnecting (try 1 of 5)...
Reconnecting (try 2 of 5)...
Reconnecting (try 3 of 5)...
Reconnecting (try 4 of 5)...
Reconnecting (try 5 of 5)...
```

As you can see I have already defined the property networkRetries=60 and it uses that value for an initial re-connection. It seems that it is able to connect then the connection apparently is broken and it starts trying to reconnect again with the value to 5.

Can you please help me with this?

**After further analysis...**

I was able to find an exception that is logged in application.log file of the OC4J_BI_FORMS:

```
17/10/31 09:37:48 web: Servlet error
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at oracle.reports.rwclient.RWClient.doGet(RWClient.java:285)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:740)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:853)
    at com.evermind[Oracle Application Server Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.2.0.2)].server.http.ResourceFilterChain.doFilter(ResourceFilterChain.java:65)
    at oracle.security.jazn.oc4j.JAZNFilter.doFilter(Unknown Source)
    at com.evermind[Oracle Application Server Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.2.0.2)].server.http.ServletRequestDispatcher.invoke(ServletRequestDispatcher.java:663)
    at com.evermind[Oracle Application Server Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.2.0.2)].server.http.ServletRequestDispatcher.forwardInternal(ServletRequestDispatcher.java:330)
    at com.evermind[Oracle Application Server Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.2.0.2)].server.http.HttpRequestHandler.processRequest(HttpRequestHandler.java:830)
    at com.evermind[Oracle Application Server Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.2.0.2)].server.http.AJPRequestHandler.run(AJPRequestHandler.java:224)
    at com.evermind[Oracle Application Server Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.2.0.2)].server.http.AJPRequestHandler.run(AJPRequestHandler.java:133)
    at com.evermind[Oracle Application Server Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.2.0.2)].util.ReleasableResourcePooledExecutor$MyWorker.run(ReleasableResourcePooledExecutor.java:192)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:534)
```

Did someone faced the same issue?

**PS:** For reference, the software was not modified in years.

Comment: are you trying for some values of `hearBeat` and `forms_timeout` env. variables beside `networkRetries`?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan , I have defined heartBeat to 58 and the forms_timeout to 60. Also session timeout is 60.